# Does anyone have a URDF model or Gazebo simulation of the Wild Thumper 6WD?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, create-robot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-

I already had materials about it with the help of Google Search .

-

I need helpful materials about its **URDF model** & its **Gazebo simulation** because there are no materials about it in **roswiki** like the other famous robots that support ROS .

-

So, I asked my question because there are a lot of experienced developers in this forum who may know helpful **materials ( links,books,tutorials)** , **sites** or **teams** that work on this robot or similar robots to it .

any help ,please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124981/does-anyone-have-a-urdf-model-or-gazebo-simulation-of-the-wild-thumper-6wd?/) by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go take a look at the [Sparkfun product page](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11056).

The Wild Thumper doesn't contain any electronics, so you won't find specific ROS drivers for it. Rather, you'll want to pick out a suitable motor controller, preferably one with ROS support.

It looks like there are a couple of people building ROS robots on top of the Wild Thumper. You may find their work useful: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=wild+thumper+ROS

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2014-02-01**:
Thanks for your help .  I already had  materials about it with the help of Google Search  . I need helpful materials about its URDF model & its Gazebo simulation  because there are no materials about it in roswiki like the other famous robots that support ROS . So, I asked my question because there are a lot of experienced developers in this forum who may know helpful materials ( links,books,tutorials) , sites or teams that work on this robot or  similar robots to it .

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-01**:
If you're looking for *specific* materials, you should indicate that you've done some initial research and ask specifically for the things you haven't been able to find. I've updated the topic of your question to be more appropriate.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2014-02-01**:
@ahendrix Thanks a lot for your help & your update . God bless you amen . Thanks also for your note ; I will take care about that .I am sorry for disturbance ,I just thought that tags of URDF & Gazebo  will express what I want.